# CCRepeatForever giving me EXC_BAD ACCESS

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, exc-bad-access

SO i'm creating a object called Enemy from the main game class
the enemy object is calling ccrepeatforever on a ccmoveto
i retained the move and repeat but still getting crashes

here is some code

```
for (Enemy *iceLord in self.children) {
if ([iceLord isKindOfClass:[Enemy class]] && iceLord.isIceLord==YES) { <-----this is where     EXC_BAD_ACCESS is showing up

//DO Stuff
 }
}
```

//inside of the enemyClass i have this method i think this is causing the crash but i can not see why

```
 -(void)startWiggle{

int randomX = (arc4random()%30)+15;
int randomY = (arc4random()%40)+15;
int dieroll = arc4random()%2+1;
if (dieroll==1) {
randomY=randomY* -1;
}
if (self.position.y < winSize.height && self.position.y >0) {
id move = [CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:1 position:CGPointMake(-randomX, randomY)];

id forever = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:move];

 [self runAction:forever];
 [move retain];
 [forever retain];
 }

 }
```

Comment: not sure why but i think this is doing something

    for (Enemy *iceLord in self.children) {
    if ([iceLord isKindOfClass:[Enemy class]] && iceLord.isIceLord==YES) { <-----this is where     EXC_BAD_ACCESS is showing up

    //DO Stuff

    //*****\ break <---this looks promising will update shortly
    }
    }

Comment: Hi. I don't think the retain count of the CCREpeatForever is the problem. Could you put everything in a `try-catch` block and print the exception? That might give us more clues. If you don't know how to do that , it's like this: `@try{ //your code } @catch(NSException *exception) { NSLog(@"exception %@" , exception.reason); }`